# Get whole screen click event

Tags: android, android-layout, touch-event

Let's assume there are all kinds of views on screen, is there any way to get every click/touch event on whole screen? And obviously I don't want to override every view's click/touch event since maybe I don't even know what views we will have.

I found that you can't even get events behind a Button.

Like I `setOnClickEvent` in `LinearLayout` which is the whole background of screen, then add a `Button` above this `LinearLayout`, when click this `Button`, Mr. Jon LinearLayout Snow knows nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override this method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();

}
```

Every touch event on opened activity will fire this method.